# What's the best way to include a ModelForm from a different Model in a Template?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following models:

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    (etc)
```

And

```
class Report(models.Model):
    complaint = models.TextField()
    picture = models.ForeignKey('Picture')
```

What i'd like to be able to do is 
a) Include the report ModelForm in the 'Picture' ModelView template
b) Prepopulate the picture field in the report Modelform with the relevant picture

I've been messing around with contextprocessors, inclusiontags and trying to pass the variable through a querystring to a new page, but they all seem quite complex and to not work correctly.

What I'd like help with is understanding the most 'django' way to do this, and any pointers to getting this done.

**Solution**

With Scott's help, the working solution is:

views.py

```
def picture(request, slug):
    picture = Picture.objects.get(slug=str(slug))
    d = dict(picture=picture, form=ReportPicture())
    d.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReportPicture(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
            report = form.save(commit=False)
            report.picture = picture
            report.save()
            return redirect(picture.get_absolute_url())
    return render_to_response("picture_detail.html", d)
```

Comment: extend your CBV `get_context_data`, `form_valid` and `post` methods. It's going to require a bit of tinkering but at the end it will work like a charm :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are wanting inline formsets ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)).

```
# models.py
class Picture(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Report(models.Model):
    complaint = models.TextField()
    picture = models.ForeignKey('Picture')


# views.py
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
from .models import Picture, Report

def manage_picture(request, pk):
    picture = Picture.objects.get(pk=pk)
    ReportInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Picture, Report)

    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = ReportInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=picture)

        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(picture.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        formset = ReportInlineFormSet(instance=picture)

    return render_to_response("manage_picture.html", {"formset": formset})
```

If you're using Class Based Views Django doesn't natively offer any inline formset support but there is an [excellent app that handles most of this for you called `django-extra_views`.](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views)

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I'm pretty sure I'm being stupid, but it's not clear to me how I'd refer to the 'manage_picture' function in the 'Picture' view - can you help?

Comment: In the example above `def manage_picture` is the view. Are you using Class Based or Function based views?

Comment: I have a class based view for the Picture object but I'd like to include the report form in this view.  I've looked through the django-extra_views app but I'm not sure that it would help with this? Thanks again.

Comment: Do you want it so one submit button sends both the Picture and Report form or do you want two separate forms with each submitting data to their respective view?

Comment: The picture element of the view is flat and contains no form. The report form will include the details of the picture that the form is rendered on.

Comment: You're probably better off solving this one of two ways. 1) For your CBV, set the `model` property to `Report` so you don't have to override all the functions associated with form processing. Additionally, you'll have to over ride `get_context_data` to grab the `Picture`. 2) Or, write a function based view and you won't have to worry about overriding anything and just write what you need.